# charset mysql db

Tags: php, mysql

i was working on a website for family but i fount a problem i can't fix and google didn't help either..

i had a problem with transoprt of a website i made, i made the website database in latin1-swedish-ci.
 but the website is made in uft-8, no problems on my host but when i transported the web page i see everywhere a question mark.
my question is how to make the database work with the char set utf-8. i tryed to make the collection to utf8-bin but nothing happents.

Thankyou,

Sander

( sorry for my poor english )

Comment: which database' (original or new) collation have you changed to utf-8?

Comment: the original becouse the webpage is utf8 i need my database to be the smae..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could either establish the connection via charset `latin-swedish-ci` and get the data correctly, or change the data inside the database into utf8 (via `mysql_set_charset('utf8', $link);`).

Remember that by changing the charset for data, I mean doing it for the database, table, and the fields. Not just the database, or the table.

Comment: And how do i change the fields to utf8 ? i changed the database and the tables to utf8-general-ci.. but still i see ?

Comment: i can do it all by hand.. but that takes years.. do you know a solution?

Comment: You can query for database fields and then run a collate SQL command for each field programmatically. It's a simple for-loop.

Comment: Thankyou now i need to set the asii characters to utf8 with `utf8_encode()` With a loop Thank you so mutch!!

Comment: You are welcome. I hope you find StackOverflow a good place to satisfy your programming needs, and in time, come back to contribute and help others out. :)